# Find div by value attribute and get html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some hidden divs with id's in html value attr. I want to find the div by value and get it's html. The problem is that my jQuery code returns undefined.

```
$( ".showComments" ).click(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('button').siblings('.writeComment').val();
    var obj = $("#myDivs[value=id]").html();
    alert(obj);
});

<div id='myDivs' value = '".$id."'>
    <div>
       <h3></h3>
       <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get the id correctly, but problem is when i tried get the divs html.

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique

Comment: ^^ my thoughts exactly, why would you need to target the value when you have the **unique indentifier** ?

Comment: How are we supposed to know what your PHP code outputs ?

Comment: I can't imagine how `closest('button')` would ever be useful code...

Comment: @lonesomeday `<button>` does accept children `<i>` and `<span>` for example. Wouldn't imagine needing `closest` though either

Comment: I have 2 buttons in button group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
   var obj = $("#myDivs[value='"+id+"']").html();
   console.log(obj);
```

Comment: It is still returning undefined.

Comment: I found the solution..i added the single quotes around id and it works : var obj = $("#myDivs[value='"+id+"']").html();

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that is wrong because it'll search for value="id" instead value="1" for example:

so you should do this:

```
var obj = $("#myDivs[value=" + id + "]").html();
```